# Levi result on $2$-Engel groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

As a reference text I use "A course in the theory of groups" by Robinson. The Levi result shows that, say G a $2$-Engel group, it satisfies:

$$[x,y,z]=[z,x,y] \ \ \forall \ x,y,z \in G$$

[his proof is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7drA5.png) (I can't put imagse in other ways)

but I don't get the part where:
$(yz)^* = y^* + z^* + y^*z^*$, I only know that in general $[x,y,z] = [x,y][x,z]^y$

What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as defined by Robinson, $y^*$ is the map $A \rightarrow A$ defined by $a \mapsto [a,y]$.

Then the identity $(yz)^* = y^* + z^* + y^*z^*$ follows from $$[a,yz] = [a,z][a,y]^z = [a,z] [a,y] [[a,y],z].$$